# CollectionView insertItem causes the whole list to be refreshed

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am using a collection view to to render a message chat thread.

Currently, when I call `self.collectionView.insertItem()`, the whole message thread seems to refresh itself.

I only want the message to be inserted into bottom of the view, and don't need/want the whole view to be refreshed.

What is the reason i am seeing whole list being refreshed?

Thanks

Comment: Show some more of your code please...

Comment: Are you calling `reloadData()` after that ? If yes, the don't. Use `reloadItems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])`